# Why is the question about killing orangutans on topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I noticed this question:

[Why would villagers attack Orangutans?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/40482/)

It has 2 upvotes, and as far as I can see, no close votes (maybe I still don't have the reputation to view them though).

The link of the question to biology is extremely tenuous, if it exists at all. OK, so humans are a subject of biology. But this is about their cultural behavior, which is not predetermined by their biology.

Is this indeed seen as a biological question? If yes, do we really want questions about human behavior on the site? Where do we draw the line to politics, sociology, economics, etc.? Do we want to answer "why do humans play cards" or "why did rich women in the 20th century wear leopard furs"?

Comment: I agree that it's not a very good question. You could argue that it falls within *Wildlife biology* (wildlife-human interactions and conflicts), which is an interdisciplinary field that includes biology. However, since the background is so poor (basically non-existant) nothing about orangutan-human conflicts and reasons for those is included in the question (beside the fact that humans arguably attack the Orangutans).

Comment: Close votes are displayed prominently under the tag: share edit close flag.